# cakephp different prefixes to access same function

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing a site that controls the budgets and other related things. And I want three users types:

- admins -> are the sysadmins controls the clients and the managers.
  Can add and modify anything.
- managers -> are the persons that controls the budgets and the persons. Can add only clients and budgets.
- clients -> only can view what managers and admins post to them.

So I have in a controller a function to add clients.

So I want that managers and admins could modify it. So the idea is to using prefix routing and create the functions admin_index and manager_index.

But are the same code and I don't want to repeat code.

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry if I haven't expressed well, I am not English and I can't express well.

My question is if I have a function in a controller called example and I have the groups admin and manager with prefix routing, I want that admin_example and manager_example redirect to the same function, in this case example, instead of putting the example code in the admin_example and manager_example.

Thanks

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with the site. Did you have a question?

Comment: Put the function in a component.  Then make two functions in your controller that both only call the component function.

Comment: @MarcB, u made my day )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, the point is to be able to open `/manager/controller/action` and `/admin/controller/action` pages and they both show the same thing, if so, then pls try this.

```
Router::connect('/manager/:controller/:action', array(
    'prefix' => 'admin'
));

Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

basically by the last line we are just "turning on" the admin routing, and by the first part, we are saying that when some page is opened and the first part is manager, just "consider" it as with admin prefix.

Comment: but Is there a way to recognize get what prefix send it??

Comment: No problem, because I use the Authentication I will check for manager or admin. Thank you